# How to get width and height of bounding rectangle of font character?

Tags: javascript, fonts, character, bounding

I am curious is it possible to get bounding rectangle width and height of font characters with javascript?

[image: enter code here]

Comment: this is something you could have just googled, and you would have found several tools that do this already, like http://opentype.js.org

Comment: Thank you! I will explore it. Looks as what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

depending on your exact implementation, you might find this useful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText() method returns a TextMetrics object that contains information about the measured text (such as its width for example).

Comment: Unfortunately: no. This API only measures the dimensions of the inline text, not of bounding box for all pixels painted by that text. The glyphs can have loads of overshoots in any direction for stylistic purposes that will not count towards the TextMetrics dimensions because they don't count "for typesetting purposes".